# Count participation of variable list

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation

I have the directed edges of a graph given by a list of variable (vertex) pairs.

```
a = 
 {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {3, 8}, {3, 11}, {4, 8},
  {5, 2}, {5, 6}, {5, 8}, {6, 8}, {6, 10}, {6, 11}, {7, 2}, {7, 6}, 
  {8, 9}, {8, 11}, {9, 6}, {10, 2}, {10, 9}, {11, 3}, {11, 4}, {11, 9}, {11, 10}};
```

I visualize it with

```
g = Graph[Rule @@@ a, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

I find the feedback loops with

```
cycles = FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

It follows that the total sublengths number 52! Therefore, I would like to know the participation of the variable corresponding to the variable list.

For example:

There are no feedback loops in variable 1. On the other hand, there are three feedback loops in variable 2. How can I count the single variable `(1, 2, 3, ..., 11)` represented in tabular form?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

The following function will find the number of loops for a particular variable:

```
countLoopsWithVar[all_, var_] := 
 Count[all, _?(MemberQ[Flatten[List @@@ #, 1], var] &)]
```

For example, `countLoopsWithVar[cycles, 1]` returns `0`; replacing `1` with `2` returns `3`.

The way it works is to convert from rules to lists and then checks whether the list is `MemberQ[var]`.

There is an alternative, which is to supply an extra argument to `FindCycle`.

```
FindCycle[{g, 2}, Infinity, All]
```

returns only the cycles which contain vertex `2`.

Comment: thanks for your useful answer. What do I do if I want to show all this count Loops on ArrayPlot with Nodesnumber and Loopsnumber

Comment: TableForm[
 Map[{#, countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #]} &, Range[11]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"node num", "number of loops"}}] might do what you want.

Comment: The function `Map` is designed for this.

Comment: How can I plot all nr. of variables like this form: {0,3,3,2,0,11,0,8,8,6,11}, there you before found the nr. variables. I have tried with countLoopsWithVar[cycles,All] comes out "0" @Patrick Stevens

Comment: (The comments have got out of order because Wolverine deleted and reposted the comment "How can I plot…" after I replied "The function `Map` is designed for this.")

Comment: I don´t really understand (I´m a new user of this program sorry).. Map[{countLoopsWithVar[cycles, #]} &, Range[11]] is it true?